# How clr calls functions with reference '&' parameters of native c++ dll?

Tags: c++, clr

I have a native c++ dll and some functions with reference-pass

> &

```
void DestroyExportObj(IExport* &pExport)
{
    pExport->Release();
    pExport = nullptr;
}
```

This works properly in native c++. And I wrapped c++ in clr

```
public ref class Class1
{
    IExport* _inst;
    ...
    void Class1::Release()
    {
        if (_inst != nullptr)
        {
            DestroyExportObj(_inst);
        }
    }
}
```

But it could not be compiled, because

> Objects in managed class members can not be converted to native references

Is it not allowed? What can I do? 
Thank you!

Comment: Try `IExport ** ppExport`

Comment: In C# imagine that it is written as `DestroyExportObj(void** pExport)`, so ``DestroyExportObj(ref IntPtr pExport)``

Comment: can not convert “cli::interior_ptr<IExport *>” to “IExport **”

Answer (score 0):

In namaged c++ you can use only pointers to native class. So, you can try to use pointer to pointer or just use wrapper for IExport. I think, that using wrapper better and anderstandably.

Comment: can not convert `cli::interior_ptr<IExport *>`  to  `IExport **`